# I can access my data from my device but cant fetch the DB request from remote device when im connected to DB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, cors, mern, http-status-code-401

So im working on a MERN stack project (I'm new to MERN stack tho,I'm working on backend)

This is my driver code

```
const {MongoClient}=require('mongodb')

let DB

module.exports={
   connectToDB:(cb)=>{
          //connecting to database of mongoserver through client
          MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ADD',{ useNewUrlParser: true, 
          useUnifiedTopology: true })
         .then(client=>{
          DB=client.db()
          return cb()
     }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('connection failed')
        return cb(err)
    })
}
,
 getDB:()=>{
       return DB
     }

}
```

This is my server code

```
const express=require('express')
const path=require('path')
const {getDB,connectToDB}=require('./database')
const cors=require('cors')
const router=require('./router')
require('dotenv').config()
const app=express()

app.use(cors({
// origin: process.env.FRONTEND_SERVER, 
origin:'*',// Allow requests from this origin
methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
credentials: true, // Enable credentials (e.g., cookies) for cross-origin requests
}));
app.use(express.json())

app.use('/api',router)
const PORT=process.env.PORT
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
console.log(`Listening at port ${PORT}`)
})
```

This is the login request in my router code

```
router.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{
   const LoginInfo=req.body;
   try{
      connectToDB(async(error)=>{
         if(error){
         console.log('Unable to connect to database')
         res.status(500).send('Internal server error')
          }
         else{
           let db=getDB()
           const user=await 
           db.collection('users').findOne({email:LoginInfo.email,key:LoginInfo.pwd})
         if(user){
            res.send('Login successful')
          }
         else{
            res.status(401).json({ message: 'Login failed' });
          }
       }
    })
   }
   catch{
     console.log(`Internal server error`)
     res.status(500).send('Internal server error')
    }
   })
```

The login works whenever i connect to compass in my device and login to the page via my device
but it doesn't work when i connect to compass in my device and try to login with correct information in other device

If i do that it shows this error to me in browser console (with status 401)

```
XHRPOST
http://localhost:3000/api/login
[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 17ms]


POST
   http://localhost:3000/api/login
Status
401
Unauthorized
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred377 B (26 B size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request PriorityHighest
DNS ResolutionSystem

    
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
    true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    http://localhost:5173
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Length
    26
Content-Type
    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date
    Sun, 31 Dec 2023 08:19:35 GMT
ETag
    W/"1a-t+HZdnkiy7+xw8RZqxZRuBMMfDI"
Keep-Alive
    timeout=5
Vary
    Origin
X-Powered-By
    Express
    
Accept
    /
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Length
    54
Content-Type
    application/json
Host
    localhost:3000
Origin
    http://localhost:5173
Referer
    http://localhost:5173/
Sec-Fetch-Dest
    empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode
    cors
Sec-Fetch-Site
    same-site
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0

REQUEST HEADER and RESPONSE HEADER

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5173
Vary: Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 26
ETag: W/"1a-t+HZdnkiy7+xw8RZqxZRuBMMfDI"
Date: Sun, 31 Dec 2023 08:19:35 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/121.0
Accept: /
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:5173/
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 54
Origin: http://localhost:5173
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
```